# How can I play an audio file by clicking a graphic using Wix?

Tags: javascript, audio, hyperlink, mp3, velo

I'm currently using Wix to help a family member build a webisite for learning English.

The site will hold hundreds of short 3-30second audio files for people to listen to while they work through the books.

To get the graphic + audio playing, I have created a static video hosted on youtube and embedded the URL in the page for the moment however I would much prefer that I can just post the image and when clicked, it plays the audio file.

I believe I need some javascript to do this however am looking to the tech gurus to guide me here

Currently I can only find a set of limited 'on click' options like, when the image is clicked it is zoomed or click to linked URL etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Image element and an AudioPlayer element. When the Image is clicked it can trigger the AudioPlayer to play the audio.

The code would look something like this:

```
$w('#myImage').onClick(() => {
  $w('#myAudioPlayer').play();
});
```

Comment: Once you see it once... it's very easy to follow. Never-the-less so helpful for what I need, thanks so much!